# Escape sequences display in python

Tags: python, string, backslash

Both `\n` and `\b` are escape sequences but why `\n` displays as `'\n'` but `\b` displays as `'\x08'`

```
>>> '\n'
'\n'
>>> '\b'
'\x08'
```

Comment: Don't forget to vote and accept the answer that helped you more to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

`\n` and `\b` are both shorthands for binary codes (`\x10` and `\x08` respectively).

Default serialization is `\xXX` but certain special characters like `\r` and `\n` CR / LF have a different serialization.